# Blurry screen on correct resolution

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr

I've connected new monitor to my Ubuntu 16.04, but the image is blurry and monitor complains "For better picture quality change resolution to 2560x1440".
The problem is that I already set my resolution to 2560x1440 in Ubuntu.

Here is my output from `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2560 x 1440, maximum 32767 x 32767
LVDS1 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   1600x900      60.01 +  40.00  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1368x768      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   1024x576      60.00  
   960x540       60.00  
   800x600       60.32    56.25  
   864x486       60.00  
   800x450       60.00  
   640x480       59.94  
   720x405       60.00  
   640x360       60.00  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 2560x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 393mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   1920x1080     60.00  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1024x768      75.08    70.07    60.00  
   832x624       74.55  
   800x600       72.19    75.00    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    66.67    60.00  
   720x400       70.08  
   test_mode     59.95  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

This is output from `get-edid`:

```
leonti ~ $ sudo get-edid | parse-edid
[sudo] password for leonti: 
This is read-edid version 3.0.2. Prepare for some fun.
Attempting to use i2c interface
No EDID on bus 0
No EDID on bus 3
No EDID on bus 4
No EDID on bus 5
No EDID on bus 6
No EDID on bus 7
No EDID on bus 8
2 potential busses found: 1 2
Will scan through until the first EDID is found.
Pass a bus number as an option to this program to go only for that one.
128-byte EDID successfully retrieved from i2c bus 1
Looks like i2c was successful. Have a good day.
Checksum Correct

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "VX3209-2K"
    ModelName "VX3209-2K"
    VendorName "VSC"
    # Monitor Manufactured week 27 of 2017
    # EDID version 1.3
    # Analog Display
    DisplaySize 700 390
    Gamma 2.20
    Option "DPMS" "true"
    Horizsync 24-82
    VertRefresh 50-75
    # Maximum pixel clock is 170MHz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1920x1080, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1680x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x1200, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1600x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1440x900, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1400x1050, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x1024, 60Hz
    #Not giving standard mode: 1280x720, 60Hz
    Modeline    "Mode 0" 241.50 2560 2608 2640 2720 1440 1443 1448 1481 -hsync +vsync 
EndSection
```

Monitor is `Viewsonic VX3209-2K` connected to Lenovo T420 via VGA cable.

I tried connecting this monitor to another laptop (Macbook) via HDMI cable and the image is sharp and I get no warning about incorrect resolution so it seems the problem is with my current setup, not with the monitor.

Are there any settings that I can adjust to the image sharp?
What can I try?

Cheers,
Leonti

Comment: The problem is most likely the VGA cable, I mean you should not expect a great image over VGA at that kind of resolution.

Comment: Try Displayport or HDMI instead.

Comment: In any way: VGA is an analogue thing. So converting digital to analogue, squeeze to VGA cable (as others already said, this is definitely a bottleneck), and digitalizing back to display is quite lossy.

Comment: My laptop doesn't support HDMI and my display port cable will arrive in the next few days, so I guess I'll have to wait. Good to know that the problem is the VGA cable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was as comments suggested with the VGA cable.

Below are notes form Lenovo T420 specs:

```
Maximum external resolution: 2560x1600 (DisplayPort)@60Hz;
                             2048x1536 (VGA)@75Hz;
                             1920x1200@60Hz (single-link DVI-D via cable 45J7915)
```

Even though my system was reading EDID file correctly it was not able to use that resolution (2560x1440) over VGA cable.

Today my DisplayPort cable arrived and I'm able to use my monitor at its native resolution.